# Maximum length of the dataset's data in charts

Tags: angular, charts

I'm trying to pass the array to the chart datasets,
so the data assigned to this is as follows.
ex:

```
 public Consumer_lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A' },
    { data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B' },
    // { data: [180, 480, 770, 90, 1000, 270, 400], label: 'Series C', yAxisID: 'y-axis-1' }
  ];
```

My doubt is what is the maximum length of data array length that can be passed to 'series A'.?!
And i have a data array length of 206 and it is not displaying anything in chart, but other graphs with small data length is working fine.

Comment: Which chart library are you used?

Comment: ng2-charts by npm wajid